# send a pdf union from phpmailer with the fpdi and fpdf libraries

Tags: php, phpmailer, fpdf, fpdi

hello good evening I have a problem when trying to send a pdf union from phpmailer that I use with the FPDI and FPDF library.

```
$filename = "example.pdf";
$document = $pdf->Output($filename, 'S');
$printpdf = merge($folders,$filename);
```

This line currently works for me as well as I have it `$mail->AddStringAttachment($document, $filename);`

but when I try to pass the variable $printpdf where it does the union of the pdfs, I don't know if I'm passing the parameters wrong
here is the example **`$mail->AddStringAttachment($printpdf, $filename);`**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some wrong syntax for fpdf. [The `Output` method](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) has this signature:

```
string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
```

and it says that all but the first is ignored in `S` mode. So if you want the PDF as a string, you need:

```
$document = $pdf->Output('S');
```

That should then work if you pass it into `addStringAttachment` as you describe. I've no idea what your `merge` function is.